# Ruby way of handling split column unordered list with count?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to plan out the design of a page using Bootstrap 4 in Ruby on Rails for a sidebar submenu that will need to expand/collapse, have some bullet points, and contain a counter.

So ultimately it needs to look like:

```
Alpha             4000
 * Major One      2000
    Minor One     500
    Minor Two     1500
 * Major Two      1000
```

Right now I'm thinking of it in terms of HTML/CSS in terms of an unordered list like:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="menu1" data-toggle="collapse">Major One</a></li>
  <ul class="collapse" id="menu1">
    <li>Minor One</li>
    <li>Minor Two</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Major Two</li>
</ul>
```

I realized that I need to put in some form of counter in the unordered list and possibly split the columns on the ul li tags that I realized...there HAS to be a Ruby way of handling this. Is there a cleaner, Ruby way, of creating an unordered list that has two columns with collapse and a count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by setting up a basic data structure:

```
@things = [
  {
    label: "Alpha",
    counter: 4000,
    children: [
      {
        label: "Major One",
        count: 2000,
        children: [
          { label: "Minor One", count: 500 },
          { label: "Minor two", count: 1500 }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Major One",
        count: 1500
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then use a partial to recursively create lists of lists:

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<ul>
  <%= render partial: 'menu_item', collection: @things, as: :item, locals: { level: 1 } %>
<ul>
```

---

```
# app/views/things/_menu_item.html.erb
<li class="<%= "level-#{level} n-#{item_counter}" %>">
  <a href="#"><%= item[:label] %></a>
  <%  if item[:children] %>
  <ul class="collapse">
    <%= render partial: 'menu_item',
        collection: item[:children],
        as: :item,
        locals: { level: level + 1 }
    %>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

`class: "level-#{level} n-#{item_counter}"` is just an example of how you can keep track of what level you are at and the index.

The output is:

```
<ul>
  <li class="level-1 n-0">
    <a href="#">Alpha</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="level-2 n-0">
        <a href="#">Major One</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="level-3 n-0">
            <a href="#">Minor One</a>
          </li>
          <li class="level-3 n-1">
            <a href="#">Minor two</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="level-2 n-1">
        <a href="#">Major One</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<ul>
```

You can of course add more keys to the hash structure to provide href´s, wrapper classes and link classes etc.